# How to infer Zod type in JSDoc (without TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, zod

Suppose I have the schema in javascript:

```js
import {z} from "zod";
let personSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  id: z.number()
});
```

now I want to use the type somewhere else:

```js
/** 
* @param {{name:string, id:number}} person 
* but should instead be something like this?:
* @param {???(typeof z)["infer"]<typeof personSchema>???} person 
*/
function (person) {
 person.name; // autocompletions and vscode linting should work here
 // do stuff
}
```

Of course this would be easy in typescript, but I'm trying to use JSDOC since the project doesn't allow TypeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to use `z.infer` to define a type using jsdoc (similar to the way you would do so in Typescript), then use the new type in the function annotation:

```js
import {z} from "zod";

/** 
* @typedef {z.infer<typeof PersonSchema>} Person
*/ 
let PersonSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  id: z.number()
});

/** 
* @param {Person} person
*/ 
function (person) {
 person.name; // autocompletions and vscode linting should work here
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: interesting that z.infer is bundled from the import. thank you!

Comment: Yes it's weird to see Javascript code (obj.function + `typeof`) executed into comments. But after all that's compilation/lining code to help DX; it is not code that will ever be executed by the application.

Comment: That works great, but many of them are classified as type any.
when i hover overr my schema : 
let ENV: {
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET?: any;
    REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET?: any;
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_EXPIRE?: any;
    REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET_EXPIRE?: any;
    COOKIE_MAX_AGE?: number;
    DATABASE_URI?: any;
    DATABASE_NAME?: any;
    NODE_ENV?: "development" | "production";
    ALLOWED_ORIGINS?: any;
    PORT?: number;
}

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```js
/** 
* @param {ReturnType<(typeof personSchema)["parse"]>} person
*/ 
function (person) {
 person.name; // autocompletions and vscode linting should work here
 // do stuff
}
```

Although this works, I suspect there is a better solution.

Comment: Following your cue, you could also define a Person type after the schema: `@typedef {ReturnType<(typeof personSchema)["parse"]>} Person`... then use `@param {Person} person` in the function's jsdoc annotation.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to take advantage of the separation between the type namespace and the values namespace by exporting the type of the schema with the same name as the schema. For example you could say

```js
export const personSchema = z.object({ /* ... */ });
// If you're using eslint, it may complain here but you can ignore
// the redeclaration complaint
export type personSchema = z.infer<typeof personSchema>;
```

When Typescript is working out the types from the JSDOC the `personSchema` type will be imported and will resolve so you get the correct value with:

```js
/**
 * @param {personSchema} person
 */
function (person) {
  person.name;
};
```

This will work with regular JS since the types won't exist so only the schema will be imported, and it will also work with TS because it can distinguish between something being used as a type and something that is a value.

Comment: Doesn't `z.infer<typeof personSchema>` require a typescript compile step though?

Comment: Right. I guess I wasn't sure what OP's exact set up is. I was thinking he was importing his schema from TypeScript code into JavaScript, but I think your interpretation is probably right and I would prefer your answer anyway since it avoids overloading the name and give a better name to the type.